# Connect to Panasonic PBX from linux box

Tags: linux, pbx

We are developing a project in a linux box and want to connect it with a existent Panasonic pbx, but it seems that there's no tool to do that, and the only way to get connected is developing yourself a windows app using the sdk from panasonic.

It will be great to hear from others with the same/similar problem and how they overcome it.

EDIT: it seems there's no solution to do it directly. The best approach we have until now is to setup a proyx machine running [Rander CTI software](http://randersoft.com/en/), and then execute some *windows scripting host* commands through a remote connection.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running it on Wine?

http://www.winehq.org/

May solve your problem if it works.

Comment: We had already tried it, but it didn't work. Thanks for suggestion :)